# How to read and combine multiple .txt files in R with multiple rows and columns into a single data frame? Data from Li-840

Tags: r

I am attempting to use R to read in and combine multiple .txt files. I would also like to add columns based on the file name. The .txt files are gas exchange data collected using the licor li-840. Each .txt file is a time series for an individual sample. The naming scheme is year.month.day.Time.Shrub.Treatment.Sample (e.g. 2021.6.9.T0.20.w3.15). The .txt file begins with a row for the date and start time. Row 2 has the 8 column names.

Edit for clarity
Goals:

- how to read in multiple .txt files
- how to delimit filenames and add as columns
- how to combine the .txt files into a single dataframe

From the comments, I tried this code:

```
files <- map(.x = cfiles, ~read.delim(.x,skip=1, header=TRUE))
%>% bind_rows()
%>% map2(.y= cfiles, ~mutate(.x, campaign = .y))
```

The output error was:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

An example of the .txt file is:
File name: 2021.6.9.T0.20.w3.15

[sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYgDc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `purrr` and `dplyr::bind_rows`

`names` will be a list of your files.

```
files <- map(.x = names, ~read.delim(.x)) %>%
          bind_rows()%>%
          map2(.y= names, ~mutate(.x, campaign = .y))
```

I have had this type of data structure before.

`purrr:map()` iterates over one single list and `purrr:map2()` iterates over two lists.

Comment: I am very new to R and this is the first time I am working with txt files. All I have so far is code to read in the files:

conductance_data <- list.files("C:/Users/jerem/OneDrive - nevada.unr.edu/Desktop/School/UNR/Thesis/Data/Y1 Conductance",pattern = "txt",full.names = T, recursive = TRUE)

What would the next steps be?

Comment: I revisited this problem and was able to create a list of the files. I modified your code to remove the first row of the .txt file and to use the second row as the header.

files <- map(.x = cfiles, ~read.delim(.x,skip=1, header=TRUE)) %>%
  bind_rows()%>%
  map2(.y= cfiles, ~mutate(.x, campaign = .y))

When I run the line it returns this error:

Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"